Twilio SMS Sandbox
I'm developing a simple SMS chatbot and using Twilio (and .NET 8 and C#), but for the time being, I can't test that things are working since I'm waiting on our A2P campaign to be approved.
Is there a way to create some sort of Twilio sandbox so as to simulate requests coming from Twilio (so I can verify my application responds correctly) and validate messages sent using Twilio API - to make sure Twilio would responds correctly given what's sent?

It's a bit of a workaround but you can start using the WhatsApp Sandbox. Both channels, SMS and WhatsApp, are very alike and the biggest difference is that the from/to fields have a "whatsapp:" prefix but other than that, it's mostly the same.
